# Add two different tables with one matching column name in SQL server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

My tables are like this:

**#table 1**

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| name     Tpens Tpencils Tbooks              |
+---------------------------------------------+
| suresh      1       2        5              |
| ramesh      3       5        7              |
| ravi        2       7        9              |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

**#table2**

```
+----------------------------------------+
| name    dpens  dpencils  dbooks        |
+----------------------------------------+
| ramesh    4        5        9          |
| prasad    5        6        7          |
| hari      7        8        9          |
+----------------------------------------+
```

I want results like

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| name     Tpens  Tpencils Tbooks dpens dpencils dbooks                                    |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| suresh   1        2        5     0        0       0    no null values                    |
| ramesh   3        5        7     4        5       9    Ramesh has values in both tables  |
| ravi     2        7        9     0        0       0                                      |
| prasad   0        0        0     5        6       7                                      |
| hari     0        0        0     7        8       9                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I wrote this query:

```
select table1.name,
        table1.tpens, 
        table1.tpencils ........etc......
        table2.dbooks 
from table1 
full outer join table2 on table1.name = table2.name
```

It gave me some null values but `prasad` and `hari` do not appear in the result table.

Comment: Left join and coalesce/isnull.

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
select 
    isnull(t1.name,t2.name) as name,
    isnull(t1.Tpens, 0) as Tpens,
    isnull(t1.Tpencils, 0) as Tpencils,
    isnull(t1.Tbooks, 0) as Tbooks,
    isnull(t2.Dpens, 0) as Dpens,
    isnull(t2.Dpencils, 0) as Dpencils,
    isnull(t2.Dbooks, 0) as Dbooks
from table1 as t1
full outer join table2 as t2 
    on t1.name = t2.name
```

Take a look at this working SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5bec0/7

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.

```
select t1.tpens
    , t1.tpencils
    , t1.tbooks
    , isnull(t2.dpens, 0) as dpens
    , isnull(t2.dpencils, 0) as dpencils
    , isnull(t2.dbooks, 0) as dbooks
from #table1 t1
left join #table2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name
```

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve what you are after:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/adc7f/6)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE one(
  name NVARCHAR(40) PRIMARY KEY,
  Tpens INT
 )
CREATE TABLE two(
  name NVARCHAR(40) PRIMARY KEY,
  Dpens INT
 )
 INSERT INTO one VALUES('bob', 5),('dave', 6), ('ravi',9)
 INSERT INTO two VALUES('bill', 4),('dave', 3), ('ravi',2)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN one.name IS NULL THEN two.name ELSE one.name END
  ,ISNULL(one.Tpens,0)
  ,ISNULL(two.Dpens,0)
FROM one 
FULL OUTER JOIN two on one.name = two.name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/adc7f/6/0)**:

```
|      |   |   |
|------|---|---|
| bill | 0 | 4 |
|  bob | 5 | 0 |
| dave | 6 | 3 |
| ravi | 9 | 2 |
```